# Cómo puedo obtener los datos de cada usuario para editar desde la ventana modal sin usar javascript o ajax?

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

Estos son los archivos requeridos para llamar los datos de la base de datos donde en la tabla se muestran correctamente:

```
<?php   
require('includes/consultar_usuario.php');
require('includes/consultar_carrera.php');
require('includes/consultar_rol.php');
?>
```

Esta es mi tabla y los datos que se muestran correctamente pero no se como llamar los datos de cada usuario para editarlos en la ventana modal

[image: Tabla]

```
<table class="tablas mb-0 table table-hover text-center">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Cedula del Usuario</th>
                                        <th>Password del Usuario</th>
                                        <th>Nombre del Usuario</th>
                                        <th>Apellido del Usuario</th>
                                        <th>Email del Usuario</th>
                                        <th>Rol del Usuario</th>
                                        <th>Carrera del Usuario</th>
                                        <th>Acciones</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    <?php

                                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario)) {
                                            ?>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><?php echo $row['usu_ci']; ?></td>
                                                <td><?php echo $row['usu_pass']; ?></td>
                                                <td><?php echo $row['usu_nombres']; ?></td>
                                                <td><?php echo $row['usu_apellidos']; ?></td>
                                                <td><?php echo $row['usu_mail']; ?></td>
                                                <td><?php echo $row['rol_nombre']; ?></td>
                                                <td><?php echo $row['carrera_nombre']; ?></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class="btn-group">
                                                        <button class="btn text-white btn-warning"
                                                                data-toggle="modal"
                                                                data-target="#modalEditarUsuario"
                                                                editarUsuario="<?php echo $row['usu_id']; ?>">
                                                            <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
                                                        </button>

                                                        <button type="button"
                                                                class="btn btn-danger btnEliminarUsuario"
                                                                idUsuario="<?php echo $row['usu_id']; ?>">
                                                            <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

Este es el modal editar donde hice lo mismo para mostrar los datos en la tabla, pero no me sale ningún resultado. He intentado lo que tengo mas conocimiento pero sigo sin tener una solución por lo que he recurrido a la vieja confiable stackoverflow

[image: Ventana Modal]

```
<form id="formulario_editar_usuario"
      method="post">
    <div class="modal fade"
         id="modalEditarUsuario"
         role="dialog"
         modal="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Editar Usuario</h5>
                    <input type="hidden"
                           name="usuarioId">
                    <button class="close"
                            type="button"
                            data-dismiss="modal"
                            aria-label="close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="position-relative form-group">
                        <label>Cedula del Usuario</label>
                        <input type="text"
                               class="form-control"
                               required
                               placeholder="Cedula"
                               name="cedulaUsuario">
                    </div>
                    <div class="position-relative form-group">
                        <label>Password del Usuario</label>
                        <input type="text"
                               class="form-control"
                               placeholder="Password"
                               required
                               name="passwordUsuario">
                    </div>
                    <div class="position-relative form-group">
                        <label>Nombre del Usuario</label>
                        <input type="text"
                               class="form-control"
                               placeholder="Nombre"
                               required
                               name="nombreUsuario">
                    </div>
                    <div class="position-relative form-group">
                        <label>Apellido del Usuario</label>
                        <input type="text"
                               class="form-control"
                               placeholder="Apellido"
                               required
                               name="apellidoUsuario">
                    </div>
                    <div class="position-relative form-group">
                        <label>Email del Usuario</label>
                        <input type="email"
                               class="form-control"
                               placeholder="Email"
                               required
                               name="emailUsuario">
                    </div>
                    <div class="position-relative form-group">
                        <label>Rol</label>
                        <select name="rolUsuario"
                                class="form-control"
                                required>
                            <option>Seleccione un Rol</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="position-relative form-group">
                        <label>Carrera</label>
                        <select name="carreraUsuario"
                                class="form-control"
                                required>
                            <option>Seleccione una Carrera</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary"
                            type="submit">Guardar
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger"
                            data-dismiss="modal">Salir
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: En la fila que requieras modificar, en el botón Editar, agrega en un atributo el código del usuario, con ello, con javascript envíalo con ajax o lo que uses para retornar los valores necesarios en tu popup.

Comment: Me recomiendas ajax a fuerzas ? Mmm no podria hacerlo directo con php esque no se me da tan bien javascript :(

Comment: Puedes poner el target del form con un nombre para la ventana emergente y abrir esa ventana en el evento onsubmit. Por ejemplo: <form name="formulario" action="destino.php?coduser=ejemplo" target="ventanaForm" onsubmit="window.open('', 'ventanaForm', '')" method="post" >
...

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer no es posible sólo con PHP, tienes que elegir: - Usar un modal sin cambiar de pantalla (PHP y Javascript) o cambiar de pantalla siempre (PHP).

Comment: Si se puede, por cada fila insertada en la tabla, crea su modal correspondiente con un form que al submit, mande al php que guarda. El php luego redirige a la tabla. No es muy aceptable en cualquier caso, pero se puede. Si quieres te hago la respuesta, pero considera hacerlo de otra forma, con ajax sería ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta esto.

```
<div class="position-relative form-group">
     <label>Cedula del Usuario</label>
     <input type="text"
        class="form-control"
        required
        placeholder="Cedula"
        name="cedulaUsuario"
        value="'.$row['usu_ci'].'">
</div>
```

pones `value="'.$row['nombre campo de la tabla'].'"`

Así, te traerá desde la DB el valor que tenga en ese campo.

Comment: Aun sigue sin mostrarme :( intente con  value="<?php echo $row['nombre_campo_bdd'];?>" y no se muestra el value se queda en blanco

Comment: $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario), estas guardando en un array en este archivo también?, de no ser así no te va funcionar.

Comment: Si en ese array estan los datos supuestamente porque abajo en el modal cuando intento ocuparlo de nuevo es como que estuviera limpio y no me indica nada

Comment: pero, tienes todo el div dentro del php?, tal vez estas concatenando mal value="<?php echo $row['nombre_campo_bdd'];?>", intenta si te funciona así value="'.<?php echo $row['nombre_campo_bdd'];?>.'"

Comment: Lo utilice como mencionas pero aun no muestra nada

Comment: $row=$consulta->fetch(), o intenta guardar en otro tipo de array, pero asi como te digo debe funcionar, mira bien la concatenación que estas haciendo dónde llamas el valor del campo.

Comment: o intenta concatenar así, value=" '+<?php echo $row['nombre_campo_bdd'];?>+' "

Comment: se imprimen los + bro mmm lo demas en teoria debe estar bien pero no entiendo que pasa

Comment: raro, value=" '.<?php echo $row['nombre_campo_bdd']?>.' ", a mi me funciono así, si encuentras como resolver avisas

Comment: Por supuesto compi apenas sepa lo posteo aqui

Comment: value=" '.<?php $row['nombre_campo_bdd']?>.' ", igual intenta sin el echo, ps el valor ya está en $row, o intenta esto tambien value=" .<?php  $row['nombre_campo_bdd']?>. "